# Example of Simple search form

Tags: search

I have a created a website using expression engine.  I would like to integrated search capability with it.

could some provide a sample code of how to integrate search and results in expression engine.  I tried to copy and paste the following from here but it doesn't show any results.:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#par_result_page

```
    {exp:search:simple_form}
            <p>
                    <label for="keywords">Search:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
            </p>
            <p>
                    <a href="{path='search/index'}">Advanced Search</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
            </p>
    {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Comment: specify in wich channels you want to search, something like that:{exp:search:simple_form channel="basis|news|products" search_in="everywhere" result_page="zoeken/resultaat" no_result_page="zoeken/geenresultaat"}

Answer (score 1):

Creating and configuring the [simple search form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html) is task one and setting up the [results template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html) is task two for your search setup.  If you follow the general examples provided in the documentation, you'll likely get most of the way there.  The simple search tags you provided above lack a few key things - the channels you wish to have searched, the nature of the search (search_in parameter), and the results page.  There are other parameters you can take advantage of to refine how the search works.